# Bipartite graph with node ordering

Tags: r, graph, igraph, bipartite

I want to create a bipartite graph in R and I want to order the two columns of nodes in the graph according to the number of outcoming and incoming links respectively.
I tried to do that with igraph, but it seems that in this package it is not possible to use a user-defined order ("the positions within the rows are optimized to minimize edge crossings, using the Sugiyama algorithm", http://igraph.org/r/doc/layout.bipartite.html).
Does someone know if it is possible to change this in igraph or if there are other packages that allow to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

igraph layout objects are simply matrices with 2 columns and one row for each vertex, so you can simply create a matrix manually where the first column is determined by calling `order()` on an appropriately constructed degree vector (which includes out-degrees for vertices of the first kind and in-degrees for vertices of the second kind), and the second column simply contains zero for vertices of the first kind and one for vertices of the second kind.